# Что использовать для кнопок вместо discord-components?

Tags: python, discord.py

Увидел что популярная библиотека discord-components попросту **устарела**

Есть ли подобные библиотеки для кнопок?

P.s чтобы можно было установить на discord.py 2.0.1

Answer (score 0):

В discord.py >= 2.0.0a есть встроенные компоненты. Пример: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/7284

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).